# How to build a line chart with several groups that is filtered with dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I created a dropdown menu to choose ID from my data. For each ID, there exists multiple INSPECTION values (this means there might be multiple lines to draw for each ID.) However, my code draws all lines connected with eaqch other and with the same color. How can I draw these lines separately and with different color?

What I have (when I choose ID a):

[image]

What I expect (when I choose ID a):

[image]

I think something I do is wrong at the end in this snippet

```
        // Draw or update the line chart
        const linePath = chart.selectAll(".line").data(Array.from(sumstat), d => d[0]);

        const colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

        linePath
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .merge(linePath)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("d", d => line(d[1]))
        .attr("stroke", (d) => colorScale(d[0]));

        linePath.exit().remove();
      }

      // Initial call to update the line chart with the first mode
      updateLine(allModes[0]);

      // When the button is changed, run the updateLine function
      d3.select("#selectButton").on("change", function (event, d) {
        // Recover the option that has been chosen
        const selectedMode = d3.select(this).property("value");
        // Run the update function with this selected option
        updateLine(selectedMode);
```

```js
data = [
  {
    "ID": "a",
    "VALUE1": "123",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "STATE": "1",
    "TIME": "00:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "a",
    "VALUE1": "100",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "STATE": "1",
    "TIME": "08:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "a",
    "VALUE1": "150",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "STATE": "1",
    "TIME": "19:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "a",
    "VALUE1": "99",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "STATE": "0",
    "TIME": "00:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "a",
    "VALUE1": "90",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "STATE": "0",
    "TIME": "10:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "a",
    "VALUE1": "102",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "STATE": "0",
    "TIME": "20:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "a",
    "VALUE1": "119",
    "INSPECTION": 2,
    "STATE": "1",
    "TIME": "01:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "a",
    "VALUE1": "111",
    "INSPECTION": 2,
    "STATE": "1",
    "TIME": "04:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "a",
    "VALUE1": "109",
    "INSPECTION": 2,
    "STATE": "1",
    "TIME": "23:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "a",
    "VALUE1": "80",
    "INSPECTION": 2,
    "STATE": "0",
    "TIME": "02:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "a",
    "VALUE1": "85",
    "INSPECTION": 2,
    "STATE": "0",
    "TIME": "11:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "a",
    "VALUE1": "99",
    "INSPECTION": 2,
    "STATE": "0",
    "TIME": "20:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "b",
    "VALUE1": "130",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "STATE": "1",
    "TIME": "01:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "b",
    "VALUE1": "99",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "STATE": "1",
    "TIME": "06:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "b",
    "VALUE1": "120",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "STATE": "1",
    "TIME": "16:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "b",
    "VALUE1": "90",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "STATE": "0",
    "TIME": "01:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "b",
    "VALUE1": "70",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "STATE": "0",
    "TIME": "11:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "b",
    "VALUE1": "85",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "STATE": "0",
    "TIME": "22:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "b",
    "VALUE1": "129",
    "INSPECTION": 2,
    "STATE": "1",
    "TIME": "00:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "b",
    "VALUE1": "101",
    "INSPECTION": 2,
    "STATE": "1",
    "TIME": "12:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "b",
    "VALUE1": "109",
    "INSPECTION": 2,
    "STATE": "1",
    "TIME": "22:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "b",
    "VALUE1": "60",
    "INSPECTION": 2,
    "STATE": "0",
    "TIME": "00:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "b",
    "VALUE1": "65",
    "INSPECTION": 2,
    "STATE": "0",
    "TIME": "03:20:00"
  },
  {
    "ID": "b",
    "VALUE1": "70",
    "INSPECTION": 2,
    "STATE": "0",
    "TIME": "23:20:00"
  }
];

    // Set up the SVG container
    const svgWidth = 600;
    const svgHeight = 400;
    const margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 50 };
    const chartWidth = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
    const chartHeight = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    const svg = d3
      .select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", svgWidth)
      .attr("height", svgHeight);

    const chart = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);


      // Parse the date string and extract only the time as hours and minutes
      const parseTime = d3.timeParse("%H:%M:%S");

      // Convert data types
      data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.TIME = parseTime(d.TIME);
        d.INSPECTION = +d.INSPECTION;
      });


      // const data = rawdata.filter(function (d) {
      //   return d.ID === '498' ;
      // });
    /* console.log(data) */
      // List of unique modes from the 'INSPECTION' column
      const allModes = Array.from(new Set(data.map((d) => d.ID)));

  // Get the maximum age and maximum height for each unique ID
  const maxData = [];
  allModes.forEach((modeID) => {
    const filteredData = data.filter((entry) => entry.ID === modeID);
    maxData.push({ ID: modeID });
  });

  // Add the options to the button with the maximum age and maximum height information
  d3.select("#selectButton")
    .selectAll("myOptions")
    .data(maxData)
    .enter()
    .append("option")
    .text(function (d) {
      return 'ID: ' + d.ID;
    })
    .attr("value", function (d) {
      return d.ID;
    });

      // Set up scales
      const xScale = d3
        .scaleTime()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, (d) => d.TIME))
        .range([0, chartWidth]);

      let xAxisGenerator = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

      const yScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 180])
        .range([chartHeight, 0]);

      // Set up axes
      const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
        .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%H:%M")) // Format the tick labels to display hour:minute
        .tickValues(xScale.ticks().concat(xScale.domain()[1])); // Add a tick value at the end of the domain

      const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

      // Add axes to the chart
      chart
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "x-axis")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${chartHeight})`)
        .call(xAxis);

      chart.append("g").attr("class", "y-axis").call(yAxis);

      // Function to update the line chart based on selected mode
      function updateLine(selectedMode) {
        let visitData = data.filter(d => d.ID == selectedMode);
        // group the data: I want to draw one line per group
        const sumstat = d3.group(visitData, d => d.INSPECTION); // nest function allows to group the calculation per level of a factor
        // Define the line function
        const line = d3
          .line()
          .x((d) => xScale(d.TIME))
          .y((d) => yScale(d.VALUE1));

        // Draw or update the line chart
        const linePath = chart.selectAll(".line").data(Array.from(sumstat), d => d[0]);

        const colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

        linePath
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .merge(linePath)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("d", d => line(d[1]))
        .attr("stroke", (d) => colorScale(d[0]));

        linePath.exit().remove();
      }

      // Initial call to update the line chart with the first mode
      updateLine(allModes[0]);

      // When the button is changed, run the updateLine function
      d3.select("#selectButton").on("change", function (event, d) {
        // Recover the option that has been chosen
        const selectedMode = d3.select(this).property("value");
        // Run the update function with this selected option
        updateLine(selectedMode);
      
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>D3 CSV Example</title>
  <select id="selectButton"></select>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Initialize a select button -->

  <style>
    /* LINE CHART */
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ed3700;
    }
  </style>

</head>
  <body>
  <h1></h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
data = [
  {
    ID: "a",
    VALUE1: "123",
    INSPECTION: 1,
    STATE: "1",
    TIME: "00:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "a",
    VALUE1: "100",
    INSPECTION: 1,
    STATE: "1",
    TIME: "08:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "a",
    VALUE1: "150",
    INSPECTION: 1,
    STATE: "1",
    TIME: "19:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "a",
    VALUE1: "99",
    INSPECTION: 1,
    STATE: "0",
    TIME: "00:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "a",
    VALUE1: "90",
    INSPECTION: 1,
    STATE: "0",
    TIME: "10:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "a",
    VALUE1: "102",
    INSPECTION: 1,
    STATE: "0",
    TIME: "20:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "a",
    VALUE1: "119",
    INSPECTION: 2,
    STATE: "1",
    TIME: "01:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "a",
    VALUE1: "111",
    INSPECTION: 2,
    STATE: "1",
    TIME: "04:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "a",
    VALUE1: "109",
    INSPECTION: 2,
    STATE: "1",
    TIME: "23:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "a",
    VALUE1: "80",
    INSPECTION: 2,
    STATE: "0",
    TIME: "02:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "a",
    VALUE1: "85",
    INSPECTION: 2,
    STATE: "0",
    TIME: "11:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "a",
    VALUE1: "99",
    INSPECTION: 2,
    STATE: "0",
    TIME: "20:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "b",
    VALUE1: "130",
    INSPECTION: 1,
    STATE: "1",
    TIME: "01:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "b",
    VALUE1: "99",
    INSPECTION: 1,
    STATE: "1",
    TIME: "06:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "b",
    VALUE1: "120",
    INSPECTION: 1,
    STATE: "1",
    TIME: "16:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "b",
    VALUE1: "90",
    INSPECTION: 1,
    STATE: "0",
    TIME: "01:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "b",
    VALUE1: "70",
    INSPECTION: 1,
    STATE: "0",
    TIME: "11:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "b",
    VALUE1: "85",
    INSPECTION: 1,
    STATE: "0",
    TIME: "22:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "b",
    VALUE1: "129",
    INSPECTION: 2,
    STATE: "1",
    TIME: "00:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "b",
    VALUE1: "101",
    INSPECTION: 2,
    STATE: "1",
    TIME: "12:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "b",
    VALUE1: "109",
    INSPECTION: 2,
    STATE: "1",
    TIME: "22:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "b",
    VALUE1: "60",
    INSPECTION: 2,
    STATE: "0",
    TIME: "00:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "b",
    VALUE1: "65",
    INSPECTION: 2,
    STATE: "0",
    TIME: "03:20:00"
  },
  {
    ID: "b",
    VALUE1: "70",
    INSPECTION: 2,
    STATE: "0",
    TIME: "23:20:00"
  }
];

// Set up the SVG container
const svgWidth = 600;
const svgHeight = 400;
const margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 50 };
const chartWidth = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
const chartHeight = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", svgWidth)
  .attr("height", svgHeight);

const chart = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

// Parse the date string and extract only the time as hours and minutes
const parseTime = d3.timeParse("%H:%M:%S");

// Convert data types
data.forEach(function (d) {
  d.TIME = parseTime(d.TIME);
  d.INSPECTION = +d.INSPECTION;
});

// const data = rawdata.filter(function (d) {
//   return d.ID === '498' ;
// });
/* console.log(data) */
// List of unique modes from the 'INSPECTION' column
const allModes = Array.from(new Set(data.map((d) => d.ID)));

// Get the maximum age and maximum height for each unique ID
const maxData = [];
allModes.forEach((modeID) => {
  const filteredData = data.filter((entry) => entry.ID === modeID);
  maxData.push({ ID: modeID });
});

// Add the options to the button with the maximum age and maximum height information
d3.select("#selectButton")
  .selectAll("myOptions")
  .data(maxData)
  .enter()
  .append("option")
  .text(function (d) {
    return "ID: " + d.ID;
  })
  .attr("value", function (d) {
    return d.ID;
  });

// Set up scales
const xScale = d3
  .scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, (d) => d.TIME))
  .range([0, chartWidth]);

let xAxisGenerator = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 180]).range([chartHeight, 0]);

// Set up axes
const xAxis = d3
  .axisBottom(xScale)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%H:%M")) // Format the tick labels to display hour:minute
  .tickValues(xScale.ticks().concat(xScale.domain()[1])); // Add a tick value at the end of the domain

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

// Add axes to the chart
chart
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "x-axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${chartHeight})`)
  .call(xAxis);

chart.append("g").attr("class", "y-axis").call(yAxis);

// Function to update the line chart based on selected mode
function updateLine(selectedMode) {
  let visitData = data.filter((d) => d.ID == selectedMode);
  let grouppedByInspection = data
    .filter((d) => d.ID == selectedMode)
    .reduce((a, b) => {
      let exist = false;
      a = a.map((w) => {
        if (w[0].INSPECTION === b.INSPECTION) {
          exist = true;
          return [...w, b];
        }
        return w;
      });
      if (!exist) {
        return [...a, [b]];
      }
      return a;
    }, []);

  grouppedByInspection = grouppedByInspection.map((a) =>
    a.sort((x, y) => x.TIME - y.TIME)
  );
  // group the data: I want to draw one line per group
  const sumstat = d3.group(visitData, (d) => d.INSPECTION); // nest function allows to group the calculation per level of a factor
  // Define the line function
  const line = d3
    .line()
    .x((d) => xScale(d.TIME))
    .y((d) => yScale(d.VALUE1));

  // Draw or update the line chart
  const linePath = chart.selectAll(".line").data(grouppedByInspection);

  const colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

  linePath
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .merge(linePath)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("d", (d) => line(d))
    .attr("stroke", (d, i) =>
      colorScale(i / grouppedByInspection.length)
    );

  linePath.exit().remove();
}

// Initial call to update the line chart with the first mode
updateLine(allModes[0]);

// When the button is changed, run the updateLine function
d3.select("#selectButton").on("change", function (event, d) {
  // Recover the option that has been chosen
  const selectedMode = d3.select(this).property("value");
  // Run the update function with this selected option
  updateLine(selectedMode);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>D3 CSV Example</title>
  <select id="selectButton"></select>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Initialize a select button -->

  <style>
    /* LINE CHART */
  
  </style>

</head>
  <body>
  <h1></h1>
```

Here you go (edit : just moved code to snippet insted of codepen)
I grouped your data in different sets

```
let grouppedByInspection = data
    .filter((d) => d.ID == selectedMode)
    .reduce((a, b) => {
      let exist = false;
      a = a.map((w) => {
        if (w[0].INSPECTION === b.INSPECTION) {
          exist = true;
          return [...w, b];
        }
        return w;
      });
      if (!exist) {
        return [...a, [b]];
      }
      return a;
    }, []);
```

Then ordered your data by time

```
  grouppedByInspection = grouppedByInspection.map((a) =>
    a.sort((x, y) => x.TIME - y.TIME)
  );
```

Finally, I rendered each set:

```
  const linePath = chart.selectAll(".line").data(grouppedByInspection);
```